# Set a new right/left delimiter for Smarty4j

Tags: java, templates, smarty

Our team is intending to use `Struts2` and `Smarty4j` to develop project. Right now, we encounter a problem:

Our `Smarty4j` template includes `JavaScript` code fragment, which causes errors and conflicts. And throughout thinking about it, I guess that The delimiter of `Smarty4j` cause this problem.

The questions I want to ask is that how to change the default `right/left delimiter` of Smarty4j (It's '(', ')' by default). Is there a convenient way to do it? by configuring or modifying Java API?

Comment: Can you show what error/conflict you are getting. Are you using a custom result type? Because I can't see how struts2 would really be having an issue with Smarty4j, we will need to see an example of what you are doing.

Comment: Because this is a plugin that developed by some Chinese, there is no sufficient resources for researching this and it's not stable, I have given up on this solution turn to others. Thanks for your reply.